# Casting void* to uint8_t* / uint16_t* properly in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I created a function which prints the elements of a table. The table has always 256 elements and the type of element might be: `uint8_t` / `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`. I do an experiment with `void` argument in function.

```
void printf_crc_table(void *pt, uint8_t crc_length) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (uint8_t k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
            switch (crc_length) {
              case 16:
                printf("0x%04X, ", *(uint16_t*)pt);
                break;
              case 32:
                printf("0x%08X, ", *(uint32_t*)pt);
                break;
              default:
                printf("0x%02X, ", *(uint8_t*)pt);
                break;
            }
            pt++; //works only for uint8_t. For uint16_t it has to be pt+=2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that increasing pointer address+1 works correctly only for `uint8_t1` table.

If I call the function with `uint16t_t` element type, every second value is incorrect. This can be repaired by increasing the pointer's address by `2`. But why? And how should I call/re-write the function that it always print correct values?

In `main` I call the function in a that way:

```
    printf_crc_table(crc8_0x07_t, 8);     // works fine
    printf_crc_table(crc16_0x1021_t, 16); // every second value is printed incorrectly.
```

I could use always `uint32_t` and cast simple `uint8_t` to `uint32_t` but I would like to use minimal resources of the micro-controller. Would it be better to use `uint32_t` instead of `void`?

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on void pointers! As there is no type the compiler can't know how much to increment.

Comment: Your compiler have to have warned you? I'm surprised it even compiled.

Comment: As the caller obviously knows what `crc_length` is you can write one function for each. If you are concerned about code space, then don't use a double loop.

Comment: Yeap, it compiles without warnings and works fine. It was also strange to me.

Comment: @Fredrik: Re “You can't do arithmetic on void pointers!”: That sentence is false as a matter of fact. The C standard does not define arithmetic on pointers to `void`. However, neither does it prohibit it. The C standard invites extensions to the language, and GCC defines arithmetic on pointers to `void`. You can do arithmetic on pointers to `void` by using GCC.

Comment: @Fredrik: Use the actual C standard, not a Stack Overflow answer. The words “legal” and “illegal” do not appear in the C standard except in reference to a hardware “illegal instruction” in a footnote. The C standard requires a diagnostic message but does not prohibit a C implementation from successfully translating a program that does arithmetic on pointers to `void`. And **as a matter of fact**, GCC supports this: When you try it, it actually happens, therefore it is possible.

Comment: @Fredrik: Referencing the standard does not mean one has stated the standard correctly. I have an official copy of the standard and just searched it for “legal” and “illegal.” Their use is as I stated. Here is a correct quote from the standard “It [a C implementation] can also successfully translate an invalid program.” The answer you link to even states that several compilers allow it.

Comment: Marcin, `crc_length` hints that the table relates to CRC data and perhaps the 16,32 bit calls need an _endian independent_ output. If so, this changes things a bit.  Could you post more info on the nature of the data to be printed?

Comment: Hi @chux- Reinstate Monica,
i dont know if i understand what do you mean. But if table is declared as uint16_t elements, I have only uint16_t data in the table. I do not mix uint8_t with uint16_t in uint16_t table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring the function with a `void *` argument is fine, but since it does not modify the data pointed to by this pointer, it should actually be declared as `const void *`. Casting the pointer on the fly as you is not very elegant and incrementing the pointer would be even more cumbersome. You could instead initialize pointers of the proper types and use these for both reading the value and incrementing.

This code does assume that the function is called with a properly aligned pointer `pt` if `crc_length` is 16 or 32.

Since you are concerned with code generation efficiency, you might want to check if defining loop index variables as `int8_t` generates smaller code than defining them as `int`.

As commented by *chux*, merely assigning the `void *` pointer to a pointer whose type does not match the effective type of the object has undefined behavior (on extremely rare architectures) so here is a modified version where the assignment is only performed for the specified `crc_length`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printf_crc_table(const void *pt, uint8_t crc_length) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (uint8_t k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
            switch (crc_length) {
              case 16: {
                  // assuming pt is properly aligned and points to an actual array of uint16_t
                  const uint16_t *p16 = pt;
                  printf("0x%04"PRIx16", ", *p16++);
                  pt = p16;
                  break;
                }
              case 32: {
                  // assuming pt is properly aligned and points to an actual array of uint32_t
                  const uint32_t *p32 = pt;
                  printf("0x%08"PRIx32", ", *p32++);
                  pt = p32;
                  break;
                }
              default: {
                  const uint8_t *p8 = pt;
                  printf("0x%02"PRIx8", ", *p8++);
                  pt = p8;
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except for "Casting the pointer on the fly as you do violates the strict aliasing rule".  The location of the casts has no particular bearing on strict-aliasing violations.  All that matters is whether the resulting pointer actually points to an object of the appropriate type. Correct code for the problem could be written with on-the-fly casts, but it would, of course, be uglier and messier than the code presented here, and the OP's is not such code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: good point! Answer amended.

Comment: `const uint16_t *p16 = pt; const uint32_t *p32 = pt;` are both potential UB:  "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @chux a reasonable assumption would be that the caller will be coherent, passing an input pointer aligned to the declared `crc_len`. Even though th strict aliasing rule, in real world I would use this simple solution rather than the other one. Ps: I've been multiply DVed for what was basicly the same answer.

Comment: Consider calling code `printf_crc_table(some_uint8_t_pointer, 8)`: "passing an input pointer aligned to the declared crc_len" - 8 in this case,  This code still attempts `uint32_t *p32 = pt;` which is UB when "resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type".  This concern is not  the strict aliasing rule.    "in real world I would use this" is likely due to not experiencing code that bus faults on mis-pointer conversion.

Comment: @chqrlie this code will fail on many platforms which require the correct access alignment.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good point, albeit quite unlikely to be a problem *in real life*. Answer amended.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland: the code will fail if the pointer argument is not properly aligned and does not point to the type implied by the `crc_length` argument. This is documented in the explanation (and I added comments in the code too).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: I did not DV your post, but they probably originated from your incrementing the `void *` pointer, which is a questionable gcc extension. There was still a bug in it after your edit: you forgot to assign the updated values of `pt16`, `pt32` and `pt8` back to `pt` for the next entry.

Comment: @chqrlie I just wonder why do you promote dangerous, unnecessary pointer punning?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland: if alignment is a specified constraint, violating the constraint may indeed result in undefined behavior. If alignment is not specified, your approach is more appropriate, even on those architectures where unaligned access is allowed. Always assuming the worst is a defensive programming approach I usually condone and I would probably use your approach. My goal here was to show the OP a simple solution that is OK for the usage specified in the question: *The table has always 256 elements and the type of element might be: `uint8_t` / `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`.*

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a portable version. Do not worry about memcpy as it will be optimized out by compilers if platform hardware allows non aligned access.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

void printf_crc_table(const void *pt, const uint8_t crc_length)
{
    union
    {
        uint8_t  data8;
        uint16_t data16;
        uint32_t data32;
    }u32;
    const unsigned char *u8ptr = pt;

    for(uint8_t i=0;i<16;i++){
        for(uint8_t k=0;k<16;k++){
            switch (crc_length) {
                case 16:
                    memcpy(&u32.data16, u8ptr, sizeof(u32.data16));
                    printf("0x%04"PRIx16", ", u32.data16);
                    u8ptr += sizeof(u32.data16);
                    break;
                case 32:
                    memcpy(&u32.data32, u8ptr, sizeof(u32.data32));
                    printf("0x%08"PRIx32", ", u32.data32);
                    u8ptr += sizeof(u32.data32);
                    break;
                default:
                    
                    printf("0x%02"PRIx8", ", *u8ptr);
                    u8ptr++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Resulting code:
Two targets: x86 allows unaligned access and memcpy was removed by the compiler, Cortex M0 does not allow unaligned access and memcpy has not been optimized out. It is a safe and portable version.

https://godbolt.org/z/MzEWdE

If you do not want to use `memcpy` you can do it another way:

```
void printf_crc_table(void *pt,uint8_t crc_length)
{
    union
    {
        uint8_t  data8[sizeof(uint32_t)];
        uint16_t data16;
        uint32_t data32;
    }u32;
    unsigned char *u8ptr = pt;

    for(uint8_t i=0;i<16;i++){
        for(uint8_t k=0;k<16;k++){
            switch (crc_length) {
                case 16:
                    u32.data8[0] = *u8ptr++;
                    u32.data8[1] = *u8ptr++;
                    printf("0x%04"PRIx16", ", u32.data16);
                    break;
                case 32:
                    u32.data8[0] = *u8ptr++;
                    u32.data8[1] = *u8ptr++;
                    u32.data8[2] = *u8ptr++;
                    u32.data8[3] = *u8ptr++;
                    printf("0x%08"PRIx32", ", u32.data32);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("0x%02"PRIx8", ", *u8ptr++);
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Byte accesses are always aligned by definition. Modern compilers will replace them with the single access instruction if hardware supports unaligned access.

https://godbolt.org/z/eqnovf

Comment: _Do not worry about memcpy as it will be optimized out by compilers if platform hardware allows non aligned access._ Optimized to what? How do you expect correct arithmetic based on multiples of misaligned addresses? Black magic?

Comment: @DavidRanieri `memcpy()` works fine here.  `memcpy()`does not require pointer alignment.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Usage of `memcpy(&u32.dataN, u8ptr, sizeof(u32.dataN))` certainly looks portable to me.  What specifically do you find non-portable about `memcpy()` usage here?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes indeed  I should add `sizeof(....)` instead of the magic number

Comment: @DavidRanieri I do no understand your comment. Explain what you actually mean. I do not see any problems with this code. `memcpy` is "well known" by most of the modern compilers and they will decide if it is safe and efficient to replace the call to `memcpy` by the direct memory reads.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland ooops I missed the word "out" in optimized out, now I understand that this means deleted by the compiler, not optimized in the sense of improved, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I have is that increasing pointer address+1 works correctly only for `uint8_t1` table.

Well yes, if we accept that `pt++` has the effect of increasing the address by 1 then it is to be expected that that will yield the correct result only if the data are 1 unit in size (i.e. the size of a `char`).  For data whose elements are other sizes, increasing the address by 1 does not result in a pointer to the next element.

And perhaps this is a key point you are missing.  `void` is not an automagical "the compiler will figure out the real type" placeholder.  It is a specific type, albeit an incomplete one.  And pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to type.

That's a problem for your code: because `pt` is a pointer to `void`, an incomplete type, pointer arithmetic involving `pt` is not defined.  Your claim in comments that your compiler does not even warn about that is surprising, and if it is true, then you would be well advised to turn up the warning level you request from it, or else choose a better compiler.

It would not be nearly as surprising for the compiler to accept the code *with* a warning, however, for some popular compilers implement an extension in which they treat arithmetic with `void *` as a special case, equivalent to arithmetic with `char *`.

I would recommend the approach in [@chqrlie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751540/2402272), supposing the alignment issue to be unlikely to be of consequence in practice.  If there is a risk that the data may not be correctly aligned for the element type then that would be something to reconsider.

For the record, however, here is a different variation on your original code that gets the pointer arithmetic right while cutting a little closer to your original:

```
void printf_crc_table(void *pt, uint8_t crc_length) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        for (uint8_t k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
            switch (crc_length) {
              case 16:
                uint16_t *p16 = pt;
                printf("0x%04X, ", *p16);
                pt = p16 + 1;
                break;
              case 32:
                uint32_t *p32 = pt;
                printf("0x%08X, ", *p32);
                pt = p32 + 1;
                break;
              default:
                uint8_t *p8 = pt
                printf("0x%02X, ", *p8);
                pt = p8 + 1
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

To the extent that chqrlie's version has alignment issues, this has the same issues.  The point being illustrated is that you can, with a little effort, maintain the data pointer as `void *` while still performing accesses and updates that are correct for the underlying element type.

Comment: `printf("0x%08X, ", *p32);` is a problem with 16-bit `int/unsigned` -- still quite popular in embedded processors.  More portable to use `PRIxN`.

Comment: This code will not compile at all. You cant define variables inside the `case` without wrapping them into the compound statement (`{}`)

Comment: `supposing the alignment issue to be unlikely to be of consequence in practice` in practice memcpy sorts out all of the problems without the penalty on most modern platforms.